# Android/iOS Analytics Enhanced ecommerce not showing anything

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've followed the steps from [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce). I've configured analytics account to show enhanced reports. I've tried all posibilites from docs examples but I'm getting no hits. I've also tried in iOS but same results. Any reason?:

```
Product product =  new Product()
    .setId("P12345")
    .setName("Android Warhol T-Shirt")
    .setCategory("Apparel/T-Shirts")
    .setBrand("Google")
    .setVariant("black")
    .setPrice(29.20)
    .setQuantity(1);
// Add the step number and additional info about the checkout to the action.
ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_CHECKOUT)
    .setCheckoutStep(1)
    .setCheckoutOptions("Visa");
HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .addProduct(product)
    .setProductAction(productAction)
    .setCategory("Ecommerce")
    .setAction("Checkout start");

tracker.setScreenName("checkoutStep1");
t.send(builder.build());
```

(I've also tested with ScreenViewBuilder with same results) I've placed tracker in verbose level and I get the following hit:

```
12-05 18:16:29.525: V/GAV4(23872): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   
PATH: https:  
PARAMS: 
  tid=UA-XXXXXXX-6,
  t=event,

  cos=1,
  ht=1417799783734,
  aid=com.myapp.debug,
  ea=Checkout,
  ec=Ecommerce,
  cd=checkoutStep1, 

  pr1id=P12345,
  pr1va=black,
  pr1ca=Apparel/T-Shirts,
  pr1pr=29.20,
  pr1cc=APPARELSALE,
  pr1nm=Android Warhol T-Shirt,
  pr1qt=1,
  pr1br=Google,
  pa=checkout,  
  col=Visa,
  ate=1,

  aiid=com.myapp.app,
  an=MyApp, 
  av=1.0.0,

  _u=.KKyADAAAAAAAAAAAL,
  ul=ca-es,
  sr=720x1280,
  a=921530729,
  cid=7a02b428-07a9-4c08-9949-5bd15e7159ad,
  v=1,
```

Comment: Right now appeared, after 1 hour of sending hits...

Comment: So it appeared eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Try such way:

```
public void sendProductAction(ProductInfo productInfo) {
    //TODO Add something that we need!
    Product product = new Product()
            .setId(productInfo.productId)
            .setPrice(productInfo.totalAmount)
            .setName(productInfo.productName)
            .setQuantity(1);

    ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
            .setTransactionId(productInfo.orderId)
            .setTransactionAffiliation(productInfo.userId)
            .setTransactionRevenue(productInfo.totalAmount);

    HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
            .addProduct(product)
            .setProductAction(productAction);

    Tracker tracker = AnalyticsManager.getInstance().getTracker(TrackerName.ECOMMERCE_TRACKER);
    tracker.set("&cu", "EUR");
    tracker.send(builder.build());
}
```

Also you should enable Enhanced Ecommerce in console affiliated with your account.